# Sleuth can't send traces to zipkin. Exportable always false

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-ecs, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

When i run my spring boot application locally i always have trace information with exportable information = true

```
[my-service-v1,d074fc20fbfe0615,d074fc20fbfe0615,true]
```

but when app running on AWS ECS in docker container i have always exportable false for all logs

```
[my-service-v1,2fa3d680aaf0d41f,2fa3d680aaf0d41f,false]
```

except classpath **org.hibernate**. On this classpath exportable = true

I use below dependencies

```
     <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And below properties :

```
spring:
  zipkin:
    base-url: http://zipkin-server
    discovery-client-enabled: true
    enabled: true
  sleuth.sampler.probability: 1.0
```

Which may be the reason for different actions ? Maybe log levels ? 
**base-url: http://zipkin-server**  must be reachable ?

Comment: Most likely it's Amazon that sets the flag to false. Is that possible?

Comment: I don' think so, maybe is docker issue, what you think ?

Comment: Hmm don't think so. Is it a problem for any endpoint?

Comment: Yes, all classes from my packages nothing export to zipkin

Comment: Please upload a sample that replicates the problem

Comment: I have the same issue; it works fine if I run it locally but inside AWS EKS (Kubernetes) it falls back to the probability based sampler with 10%.